# Optimizing A* Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, a-star

I've recently implemented the A* algorithm for my agent based model which using a 2D array. The purpose of the search is to give the agents a list of locations that lead to the goal location. My implementation works, however some times when I execute the algorithm it returns an alternative path which is still connected to the main path. I don't understand why its doing this. Code it below:
http://pbrd.co/1DFaeIr

```
public boolean generatePath(Location startLocation, Location goalLocation) {
        setUpStartingPoint(startLocation, goalLocation); //Set up everything before search 
        boolean pathExist = false;
        int loop = 0;

        openList.add(startNode); //Put start node in openList (Initial starting point)
        while(pathExist == false) {
            if(openList.isEmpty() ==  false) { //More locations to check
                System.out.println("Step: " + loop);
                System.out.println(currentNode);
                System.out.println(openList);
                System.out.println(closedList);

                reOrderList(openList);
                Node lowestFvalueNode = openList.remove(0); //Get the node with the lowest F value in openList
                lowestFvalueNode.setParent(currentNode);
                currentNode = lowestFvalueNode;
                closedList.add(lowestFvalueNode);

                if(checkNodeInList(closedList, goalNode)) {
                    System.out.println("Found");
                    computeCurrentPath(currentNode);
                    pathExist = true;
                }
                else {
                    ArrayList<Node> currentNodeAdjNodes = getAdjacentNodes(currentNode);
                    for(Node adjNode : currentNodeAdjNodes) {
                        if(checkNodeInList(closedList, adjNode)) { //If node is in the closedList

                        }
                        else {
                            if(checkNodeInList(openList, adjNode) == false) {
                                computeNodeValues(adjNode); //Compute the G,H and F values of node
                                adjNode.setParent(currentNode); //Set the nodes parent as current node
                                openList.add(adjNode); //Add node to open list
                            }
                            else {
                                Node actualAdjNodeInOpenList = getNodeInList(openList, adjNode);
                                int currentMovementCostToNode = currentNode.getGvalue() + getMovementCostToNode(currentNode, adjNode);

                                if(currentMovementCostToNode < adjNode.getGvalue()) {
                                    computeNodeValues(adjNode);
                                    adjNode.setParent(currentNode);
                                    reOrderList(openList);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                loop++;
            }
            else {
                pathExist = false;
                System.out.println("Path doesn't exist");
                return false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(path);
        return pathExist;
    }
```

Comment: "it returns an alternative path which is still connected to the main path" is a little ambiguous. What can you tell us about these path lengths? Is this alternative path suboptimal?

Comment: See the edited post ive added a screenshot of the path being printed

Comment: Here's a link to a screenshot: http://pbrd.co/1DFaeIr

Answer (score 0):

If the path is optimal as well then it does not matter which one you choose. There is a way to optimize the algorithm that is worth giving a try: use A* along with Beam search. Beam search will reduce the memory space needed.

Comment: The other locations its giving basically lead to a dead end I dont understand why the alvoirth

Comment: The locations its giving basically lead to a dead end, i think its because its picking between two nodes with the same F value in the openlist. Whats the best why to determin which node is next to pick if they both have the same F values ?

Comment: @user3112844: If two nodes have the same F = G(x) + H(x) where G is the work/distance done to get to node x and H is the heuristic of work/distance remaining from x to soln, then it is equivalent to pick either. If your heuristic is not admissable, then you are not guaranteed anything about the optimality of your soln, although you can still do pretty good in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination Andy, whats best wait in making your heuristic admissable in order have a optimal path generated

Comment: In 2D, you can use Manhattan distance so long as you don't move diagonally, which will be optimal for shortest path problems. This is (# of columns from goal + # of rows from goal). Basically, an admissable heuristic never overestimates cost to reach goal (it's "optimistic")

Comment: I dnt think my version of the algoirtm  is effiecent its taking way to long to work out a path with a maze like struture. I can seem to find a online pseduo code of the algoritm can reference me to any please regards.

Comment: @user3112844: You don't seem to actually use `actualAdjNodeInOpenList ` when it appears you meant to get/set its movement cost.